# I don't understand Swift Unicode Scalar basics. What am I missing

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm just starting my Swift journey so please forgive my ignorance.

```
UnicodeScalar("H") => 72
"\u{72}" => "r"
```

What am I not understanding here?  Why are these not equal?
Where can I lookup unicode scalar values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of confusion between decimal and hexadecimal numbers.

This

```
UnicodeScalar("H") => 72
```

is the *decimal* value of the scalar.

This

```
"\u{72}" => "r"
```

is supplying the scalar value in *hexadecimal*.

If you want to create "H" by supplying the scalar value, you need to give 72 in hex, which is 0x48.

```
"\u{48}" => "H"
```

You can find charts of Unicode scalar values using a web search. The [official charts](http://unicode.org/charts/) are at the Unicode consortium.

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense now. Ty.